# jenkins jobcopy builder plugin not working

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

```
Started by user user
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/JobBuilder
Copying Template to TemplateNew
Error: Item 'Template 'was not found.
Build step 'Copy Job' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

It's giving above error though Template project exits. Am I missing anything?. In the log it is showing 'Template ', Why the space is getting adding?. I'm sure that I did not give any space while project creation.

Comment: Could you paste a screenshot of your copy job build step?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5FSzOhtHwwEWUl6RzhQeGMwbDA

Comment: @DanielOmoto Did you get it?

Comment: Thanks for providing more information regarding other names/jobs do not work as well.  I've deleted my answer since it did not work.  Hopefully someone else will come along and be able to provide a solution..  If I have some free time, I'll also try to reproduce the issue again.

Comment: I had the same issue. I guess no one found the solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a permission issue

Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security > Under Authorization > Select Project-base Matrix Authorization Strategy

Add Permission
Since "Copy Job" is run as ANONYMOUS as default
Look permission you want to add [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jobcopy+Builder+plugin)